# How do you execute a method on the ObjectDataProvider bound to a Button when it is clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need my `ObjectDataProvider` method to execute on the click of my button with whatever happens to be bound to the 2 method parameters at the time. But i get an immediate run-time error with the error below.

Here is my XAML code that contains a run-time error on my last button's Click event.

```
<Window x:Class="LoginNS.LoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginNS"
    Title="LoginWindow" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="254" Width="438" Opacity="1" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFB10000">

<Window.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid Width="400" Height="200">
    <Rectangle x:Name="LoginRectangle" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stroke="#FF7E0000" Width="400" RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40" Fill="#DC840000" StrokeThickness="4" />
    <Button x:Name="ExitButton" Style="{StaticResource ExitButton}" Click="exitButtonMethod" />
    <TextBox x:Name="UsernameTextbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="64,69,0,0" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="#FF7E0000" BorderThickness="2" Background="{StaticResource LoginGradient}" Foreground="#FF7E0000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273"
            Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LoginConnectToDB},
            Path=MethodParameters[0],BindsDirectlyToSource=true}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="PasswordTextbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="64,104,0,0" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="#FF7E0000" BorderThickness="2" Background="{StaticResource LoginGradient}" Foreground="#FF7E0000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273"
             Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LoginConnectToDB},
            Path=MethodParameters[1],BindsDirectlyToSource=true}"/>
    <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Style="{StaticResource LoginButton}" Click="{StaticResource LoginConnectToDB}"/>

</Grid>

</Window>
```

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.Click' threw an exception.' Line number '28' and line position '38'.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Click` is an event. It cannot be bound to the DataContext.  The Click event can be responded to through the `Click` attribute, but that maps to a function on the Window or Control instead of the bound DataContext.

`Command` is a `DependencyProperty` it *can* (and should) be bound to an `ICommand` object. `DelegateCommand` is a very useful (and simple) implementation:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
       return true;
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Full example at: http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html

In the command's execute (or in the method passed to `DelegateCommand` you would perform your data refresh.